# JAVA Shopping Cart Exercise Not Compiling When printMenu() Is Called

Tags: java, cart

I am working on an assignment in which I have to create a simple shopping cart with a menu. However, I am very stuck as I can't figure out why my printMenu() method will not compile. Aside from that, I feel pretty good about the rest of the code.

To understand what exactly I'm required to have/use for this assignment, I will have the instructions posted here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u3be.jpg

The actual code files can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/EJCwWeeV)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ShoppingCartManager
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ShoppingCart cart = new ShoppingCart();
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        String customerName = "none";
        String currentDate = "January 1, 2017";

        System.out.println("Enter Customer's Name:");
        cart.setCustomerName(scnr.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter Today's Date:");
        cart.setDate(scnr.nextLine());
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Customer Name: " + cart.getCustomerName());
        System.out.println("Today's Date: " + cart.getDate());

     cart.printMenu();
    }

}
```

Comment: please post your whole code with the printMenu()

Comment: Thats because your printMenu(ShoppingCart cart) is expecting an arugment of type ShoppingCart  but you are not sending it in your main. Change the printMenu in ShoppingCart as public static void printMenu().

Answer (score 0):

Your `printMenu` function is `static`, meaning you call it at the class level, and pass a `ShoppingCart` as an argument.

```
ShoppingCart.printMenu(cart);
```